# $i18nextProvider in karma test

Tags: angularjs, typescript, karma-jasmine

I try to run a test for a directive which uses i18next.

my karma.conf.js contains following path:

```
 'bower_components/ng-i18next/dist/ng-i18next.js',
```

But in the test I am getting

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating
>   '$element.text.bind($element)')

with reference to:

> /bower_components/ng-i18next/dist/ng-i18next.js:228

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS doesn't provide an implementation of bind, you should use a polyfill, one is provided in i18next repository:

https://github.com/i18next/ng-i18next/blob/master/test/polyfills/bind.js

Then you must load the polyfill in PhantomJS, usually in 'files' section in karma.conf.js